# Split DataFrame by grouping column values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame

```
S   C
3   2
3   2
3   2
3   2
3   2
3   2
1   4
1   4
1   4
1   4
1   4
1   4
```

How can i split the dataframe so that one dataframe has 3 and 2 in S and C and other has 1 and 4 in S and C

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a comprehension with `groupby`

1. The key element is `df.groupby` which provides the grouping you desire.
2. However, you need to facilitate this into a list so that you have "split" it into separate data frames.
3. You can iterate through the groupby object which passes a tuple where the first element is the name of the group (we mask this with `_`) and the second element is the individual data frame.
4. By using a comprehension, we can iterate through the groupby and capture the second element of each tuple... thus creating a list of data frames.

**See:**
[**List Comprehensions**](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)
[**Grouping Stuff**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html)

---

```
list_of_df = [g for _, g in df.groupby(['NUMBER_OF_TRIPS', 'SERVICE_CLASS'])]

print(*list_of_df, sep='\n\n')

    NUMBER_OF_TRIPS  SERVICE_CLASS
6                 1              4
7                 1              4
8                 1              4
9                 1              4
10                1              4
11                1              4

   NUMBER_OF_TRIPS  SERVICE_CLASS
0                3              2
1                3              2
2                3              2
3                3              2
4                3              2
5                3              2
```

Comment: Thank you for your code, since i am new to python, can you please help me explaining how this code works?